# mysql combine query results side by side

Tags: mysql

Simple question that I cant get my head around.
I want to just combine two tables with no common data side by side.

```
table1    table2   ->   result 
a  b       e  f          a  b  e  f
c  d       g  h          c  d  g  h
           i  j          \n \n i  j
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `RIGHT JOIN` and assign an id to each of your tables using `ROW_NUMBER`. See my query below:

```
 SELECT A.column1,A.column2,B.column1,B.column2 FROM
    (SELECT
         @row_number1:=@row_number1+1 AS RowNumber1,
         column1,
         column2
    FROM Table1, (SELECT @row_number1:=0)AS x ORDER BY column1) AS A
    RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT
         @row_number2:=@row_number2+1 AS RowNumber2,
         column1,
         column2
    FROM Table2, (SELECT @row_number2:=0)AS y ORDER BY column1) AS B
    ON A.RowNumber1=B.RowNumber2
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great! I had to change inner join to right join as they had different lengths but that worked then. A bit more complicated than i thought it would be.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables are inherently unordered, so a key for ordering the rows is desirable.  You can create one, using variables.

Your tables have different numbers of rows.  That means that a `full outer join` is desirable, but that's not available in MySQL.  So, you can do what you want with aggregation and `union all`:

```
select max(col1) as col1, max(col2) as col2, max(col3) as col3, max(col4) as col4
from ((select col1, col2, null as col3, null as col4, @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 as rn
       from table1 cross join (select @rn1 := 0) vars
      ) union all
      (select null, null, col3, col4, @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 as rn
       from table2 cross join (select @rn2 := 0) vars
      )
     ) tt
group by rn
```