# MySQL joining 2 queries

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to take the results of

```
SELECT SUM(pont) AS totalpont
      FROM
    (SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j1 
    UNION 
    SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j2
    UNION
    SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j3 
    UNION
    SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j4) T
```

and

```
SELECT mercado FROM variaveis
```

into same query, two independent data sets side-by-side, e.g. query 1 returns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and query 2 returns A, B, C. I want result to be 1,A, 2,B, 3,C, 4,null, 5,null

Comment: Rafel , could you explain more about your question what you wan to achieve?

Comment: i need to join these two queries in one.

Comment: UNION combines two Queries by LINES, not by ROWS, what you need is a vertical join, so you need to use a JOIN operation.

Comment: @RafaelFrug Could you see my answer  that is what you want to achieve ?

Comment: yes, i need a JOIN but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: @RafaelFrug If you need to Join you can use any ID(primary key) columns in your table. More curious , at least I  have no idea what is your column names are ? Could you update those , so everyone  will easy to get what the operation for

Comment: Is this like two independent data sets that you just want side-by-side, e.g. query 1 returns `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` and query 2 returns `A`, `B`, `C` you want result to be `1,A`, `2,B`, `3,C`, `4,null`, `5,null`? If so, update the question to say something like that.

Comment: @Andreas yea, gonna update now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql combine query results side by side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685992/mysql-combine-query-results-side-by-side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you need to merge these queries and need a single SUM, for that you can use 'AS' syntax (rename the mercado as pont) so you can sum.

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(pont, 0)) as totalpont, SUM(COALESCE(mercado, 0)) AS totalmercado
      FROM
    (SELECT jogador.pont, NULL AS mercado from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j1 
    UNION 
    SELECT jogador.pont, NULL AS mercado from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j2
    UNION
    SELECT jogador.pont, NULL AS mercado from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j3 
    UNION
    SELECT jogador.pont, NULL AS mercado from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j4) T
    UNION
    SELECT NULL AS pont, mercado  FROM variaveis )T
```

Comment: using UNION i have a single line, i want to work with the data of "pont" and "mercado" separately

Comment: @RafaelFrug Please see the updated query which will have both columns on each result (pont, mercado).

Comment: still doesnt work, i think i can't use UNION to do this.

Comment: @RafaelFrug , Please update the sample output ,so we can get more details

Comment: I'm gettin


totalpont
72
1

and want to 
totalpont 72 --- mercado 1

get it?

Comment: @RafaelFrug Please try the updated query now, earlier I missed one more sum, I think that's what you want :-)

Comment: Adding COALESCE to handle NULL values

Comment: ok, now i need to get the first line of the first select and the second line of the second select, any idea?

Comment: @RafaelFrug Could you give me an example? How your output needs to be?

Comment: i removed the coalesce because i didnt need it and got this: http://i.imgur.com/WQXHKkA.png , but i want this: http://i.imgur.com/H3LuKal.png

Comment: Could you paste the image of the running query ? It seems to be some issue in the query , it seems logic is perfect.

Comment: Please move this string " ) T " to end after table name  variaveis and try , let me know if that works too

Comment: Updated query also , please see the answer again