# MYSQL Select distinct values in different column in more than 2 joined table

Tags: mysql, join

Suppose we have 3 tables TableA, TableB, TableC. Structure of tables is like:

```
TableA:(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6)
TableB:(B1,B2,B3)
TableC:(C1,C2,C3)
```

where A1,B1 and C1 are the Auto Incremented PRIMARY KEYS of their respective tables.

Now , I am trying to fetch some results using a Left Outer Join.
Here is the Query:

```
select A.A2, A.A3, B.B2, C.C2 from TableA as A left outer join TableB as B
on A.A4 = B.B3 left outer join TableC as C on A.A5 = C.C3 where A.A1 = 1
```

Now, this query return me a table where results are repeated.

```
A.A2| A.A3| B.B2| C.C2
x   | y   |p    |u
x   | y   |p    |v
x   | y   |q    |u
x   | y   |q    |v
x   | y   |r    |u
x   | y   |r    |v
```

Now, for a particular value of A.A1 , there would be only one and only one value of x and y. But There is a 1:n relation between TableA and TableB as well as TableA and TableC. Also, A.A4 and A.A5 serve as a foreign key for Respective tables.

I want a table where i can have only distinct values (At least for  B.B2 and C.C2 ). I have tried :

```
select distinct A.A2, A.A3, B.B2, C.C2 from TableA as A left outer join TableB as B
on A.A4 = B.B3 left outer join TableC as C on A.A5 = C.C3 where A.A1 = 1
```

DISTINCT and GROUP BY on B.B2 and C.C2 to obtain the result i want, but not able to do so. I want the resultant table to be like this:

```
A.A2| A.A3| B.B2| C.C2
x   | y   |p    |u
x   | y   |q    |v
x   | y   |r    |
```

where I have only distinct values of B.B2 and C.C2. To solve this problem, I could have done separate operations and then combined result to achieve my goal. But I want to do this by joining all three Tables.So how can i do this?

Comment: add - GROUP BY B.B2, C.C2 ORDER BY B.B2, C.C2

Comment: @BerndBuffenAlready tried this. Result in still same.

Comment: Can you please describe again what rows you want? If you say, you want "only distinct values (At least for B.B2 and C.C2)", how did you get your result-table where you ommit the value ' q' value in C2? Would any of these 4 combinations of 2 rows: (x,y,p,u)+(x,y,p,v) (this is your example), (x,y,p,u)+(x,y,q,u), (x,y,p,v)+(x,y,q,v) and (x,y,q,u)+(x,y,q,v) be valid solutions (and the code can choose any of these)? If not, can you please describe again (exactly!)? If yes: can you give an example where c2 has everywhere the same value but b2 not. And where b2 has e.g. 3 values and b2 just 2 values.

Comment: @Solarflare I have edited the question.please have a look again.

Comment: You didn't answer my questions. You might have to explain what you mean by "distinct values of B.B2 and C.C2", because you seem to have a different understanding of that than I. E.g. why can you have 2 ps in B2, but not 2 us in C2. Why do you get your result and not any of the 3 results i proposed in my comment. Please add the code for: "To solve this problem, I could have done separate operations and then combined result to achieve my goal.". Maybe we will then understand what you want (because that code might describe it more clearly than you can) and build a join with the same result.

Comment: Ok, after your edits that removed that error in your example(!) I think i got what you want. You want to have two lists with the values of entries from B2 and C3 that start at row 1 and have nothing to do with each other, right? So basically something that has nothing to do with joins (or how databases work). It is possible (generate the distinct lists from b2 and c3, each with a rownumber, left join them by the rownumber and cross join them with A), but it's nothing a database should do. Better use your seperate querys - why join something you actually don't want to be joined?

Comment: And you might want to describe what you actually want to achieve by this, it looks to me as if you are trying to solve a problem with the wrong tool, see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Please have a look at the table above and below. Whenever you do a join, there is a repeatation of rows like it is in table above. By distinct values in B.B2 and C.C2 , i mean to remove duplicate entries in the table above and make my table somewhat similar to table below. In the given example above, you can notice that the values in column B.B2 and C.C2 are repeated. Whereas I want a result similar to table drawn below with only distinct values in column B.B2 and C.C2. I cannot share my code since my organization does not allow me to do so.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685992/mysql-combine-query-results-side-by-side, it solves your problem as i described it (you just have to add the cross join with table A to this solution).

Comment: Basically, earlier when i coded this, there were only two tables.So ,i did it with join. Eventually,now I have one more table and could be more in future. So wanted to stick with join and was looking for some method so that i can get what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to plit your query into 2 separate joints with A table, specifically A-B and A-C, and then join the two result sets using primary key of the A table:

```
SELECT AB.A1, AB.A2, AB.A3, B2, C2
FROM
    ( select A.A1, A.A2, A.A3, B.B2
    from TableA as A left outer join TableB as B on A.A4 = B.B3
    where A.A1 = 1 ) AS AB
LEFT JOIN
    (select A.A1, C.C2
    left outer join TableC as C on A.A5 = C.C3 where A.A1 = 1
    where A.A1 = 1 ) AS AC ON AB.A1 = AC.A1
```